# What do the various components of a contract displayed in Truffle mean?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Using Truffle and the CryptoZombies example code, when I type ZombieFactory.deployed() the contract is shown with all of its functions. For example,

```
createRandomZombie:
  { [Function: bound ]
    request: [Function: bound ],
    call: [Function: bound ],
    sendTransaction: [Function: bound ],
    estimateGas: [Function: bound ],
    getData: [Function: bound ],
    string: [Circular] },
 allEvents: [Function: bound ],
 NewZombie: { [Function: bound ] 'uint256,string,uint256': [Function: bound ] },
 OwnershipTransferred: { [Function: bound ] 'address,address': [Function: bound ] } },
```

What does [Function: bound] mean? Why are request and call shown? They are not separate functions that are in the Solidity file.

Answer (score 1):

Truffle for every contract function it creates several "shortcuts":

- `function()` will create a transaction and wait for it to be mined,
- `function.sendTransaction()` will create a transaction and return immediately the txhash,
- `function.call()` will make a call overriding the abi definition (will not modify the contract state),
- `function.estimateGas()` will estimate the execution gas,
- `function.request()` return the JSON-RPC formatted command.

Comment: what does it mean for a call to override abi definition? would not the call have to be compatible with the function definition?

Comment: The abi specifies for each function if it is constant or not. Truffle will map `function()` to the default operation, ie constant function will make a call, and non constant function will make a transaction. Using `.sendTransaction()` or `.call()` you can override the default behavior.

Comment: Please point me to what a "constant function" is in the case here (I think) of Solidity is. Also, does an abi not do *more* than specify constant or not?

Comment: A constant function is a function that doesn't modify the contract storage, for example querying a token balance. Non constant functions are the ones that modify the contract storage, for example a transfer of tokens because it has to adjust the balances of sender and recipient. The solidity abi is complex, you can look at the latest specification https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/abi-spec.html.